# How to work jQuery AJAX with PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a jquery ajax request like;

```
$.ajax({
url : 'fun_val_itmco.php',
type : 'POST',
data : "agnco="+agnco+"&itmco="+itmco,
dataType : 'json',
success : function(data){                       
    //How to get array data separately?
    //itmid ?
    //itmco ?
    //itmna ?
}        
});
```

The handler fun_val_itmco.php is set to return an array like;

```
$agco=htmlspecialchars(trim(@$_POST['agnco']));
$itco=htmlspecialchars(trim(@$_POST['itmco']));

$str=mysql_query("SELECT `iid`, `ico`, `ina`, `cvl`  FROM `itemmas` WHERE `aco`='".$agco."' AND `ico`='".$itco."'");
$dar=mysql_fetch_array($str);
$display_json = array();
$json_arr = array();
try {
    $json_arr["itmid"]=$dar['iid'];
    $json_arr["itmco"]=$dar['ico'];
    $json_arr["itmna"]=$dar['ina'];
    array_push($display_json, $json_arr);       
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode($display_json);
```

Please Help me, How to get array data separately?

Comment: jeroen has given the correct answer. Additionally (but off topic), why do you have a try catch block around array assignments? Those assignments are never going to throw an Exception, much less a PDOException.

Comment: I Do That      console.log(data);
      var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      var itmid=json_obj[0].itmid;
      var itmco=json_obj[0].itmco;
      var itmna=json_obj[0].itmna;
      var itmcv=json_obj[0].itmcv;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn your data string into an object. You can do that with jQuery's [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: @ABShaman In your post, you have your success function. Inside that, you simply paste the code i have provided above, and change the content of the alert into *obj.itmid*. It will alert the data you put into that variable. It changes the data (which will be returned inside the *success* function) into an object, where you can get any element inside that dataset, by just adding it after the object you just created.

Comment: That's not necessary, the json has already been parsed by jQuery if it is valid.

Comment: ok, i do that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the results to an empty array and although that seems unnecessary, that's why you need to add an array index to access the values:

```
data[0].itmid
data[0].timco
// etc.
```

Removing the `array_push` line and just using `$json_arr` would make that easier.

Apart from that:

- `htmlspecialchars` is not the correct way to protect against sql injection, you should switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements or use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you really must;
- You are not going to get any PDO exceptions using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.